# Powershell parameter sets of same type

Tags: powershell, types

I'm trying to write a function in powershell that will take one or two arguments.

One parameter set would take a first and last name
the other would take a username.
Obviously all three of them are strings, but I want the user to be able to just type

```
Get-Info <Username>
```

or

```
Get-Info <FirstName> <LastName>
```

without having to name the parameters.
BUT if they DID name the parameters, they could potentially put only a FirstName or only a LastName which would be fine.
e.g.

```
Get-Info -FirstName John
Get-Info -LastName Doe
```

Any tips on how to get Powershell to default to the correct case with no named parameters in the command?

**Example of code with error:**

```
clear-host
function Get-Info {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Username',PositionalBinding=$true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Username', Position=0)]
        [string]$Username
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=0)]
        [string]$FirstName 
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=1)]
        [string]$LastName
    )
    process {
        "Username: $Username"
        "FirstName: $FirstName"
        "LastName: $LastName"
    }
}

Get-Info "myUsername"
Get-Info "myFirst" "myLast" #this doesn't work, as myFirst is bound to Username, and the Username parameterset has no second parameter
Get-Info -Username "Username by Param Name"
Get-Info -FirstName "FirstOnly"
Get-Info -LastName "LastOnly"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to use `ValueFromPipeline` to pass the username only parameter in a different way; e.g.

```
clear-host
function Get-Info {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Username',PositionalBinding=$true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Username', ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$Username
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=0)]
        [string]$FirstName 
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=1)]
        [string]$LastName
    )
    process {
        "Username: $Username"
        "FirstName: $FirstName"
        "LastName: $LastName"
    }
}

"myUsername" | Get-Info
Get-Info "myFirst" "myLast" | write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Info -Username "Username by Param Name"
Get-Info -FirstName "FirstOnly" | write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Info -LastName "LastOnly"
```

Not a great solution though; especially as there's a better workaround (i.e. using named parameters).

I couldn't figure out a way to implement overloading as you've described; though I see why you'd expect it to be possible.

---

**Update**

Another workaround is to provide a dummy parameter, then add logic to remap the parameter's values; e.g.

```
clear-host
function Get-Info {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Username',PositionalBinding=$true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Username', Position=0)]
        [string]$Username
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Username', Position=1)]
        [string]$Hack = $null
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=0)]
        [string]$FirstName 
        ,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', Position=1)]
        [string]$LastName
    )
    begin {
        if (($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Username') -and (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Hack) )) {
            $PSCmdlet_ParameterSetName = 'Name' #since we can't assign to $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName we may want a local variable to say which parameter set we're using
            $FirstName = $Username
            $LastName = $Hack
            $Username = $null
            $Hack = $null
        } else {
            $PSCmdlet_ParameterSetName = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
        }
    }
    process {
        "Username: $Username"
        "FirstName: $FirstName"
        "LastName: $LastName"
    }
}

Get-Info "myUsername" 
Get-Info "myFirst" "myLast" | write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Info -Username "Username by Param Name"
Get-Info -FirstName "FirstOnly" | write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Info -LastName "LastOnly"
```

Comment: Thanks, JohnLBevan, it wasn't quite what I was looking for but that second option will probably have to do. Clever thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the position attribute in your parameter declaration to set the order of the parameters which mean you don't have to name the parameters themselves, just the values.

"When the Position keyword is not specified, the cmdlet parameter must be referenced by its name."

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714348(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This doesn't work quite as expected.
As with the example in the question (Thanks @JohnLBevan !)
When giving `Get-Info firstname lastname` an error is returned that _A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'lastname'_
because it's binding 'firstname' to the Username paramter